# Pytesseract traceback error "file not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract

I'm trying to use pytesseract for OCR.

I have installed google tesseract 3.03
I have installed pytesseract 0.1.6
I am running Python 3.5.1
I am running Windows 8
Tesseract is also in my path (I can call it from anywhere in a normal CMD and it will return the help function)

And this is the code I try to execute:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

im=Image.open('C:/Users/NeusAap/Google Drive/School/Jaar 1/Periode 1/Programming/Miniproject/GarageProject/scripts/test.png')
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

But it returns this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/NeusAap/Google Drive/School/Jaar 1/Periode 1/Programming/Miniproject/GarageProject/scripts/main.py", line 8, in <module>
 print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
File "C:\Users\NeusAap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 161, in image_to_string
 config=config)
File "C:\Users\NeusAap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 94, in run_tesseract
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "C:\Users\NeusAap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
 restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\NeusAap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
 startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I know that both tesseract and pytesseract work because if I run this from CMD:

```
python pytesseract.py -l eng+nld test.png
```

It does work, and returns me the characters as expected.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Mats de Waard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. Seems like everything was set up right, and that I was calling everything correctly, but I needed to reboot Windows, because the files could not be found by Python.

I forgot that windows debugging always starts with a reboot :P